# Laravel using skip and take limiting query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sql-limit

I'm trying to build a query that uses skip() and take() functions, for some reason it keeps adding `offset 0` at the end instead it should be `LIMIT 0,0`

Code:

```
    $dbSearch = new SchoolInfo;
    $dbSearch = $dbSearch->where(function($query) use($search) {

        $query->where('school_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_1', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_2', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_3', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('address_4', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('county', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('postcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('head_teacher_email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('head_teacher_first', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('head_teacher_last', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
    });
    $results = $dbSearch
        ->skip($startat)
        ->take($startat)
        ->orderBy('school_name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

And this is the error I get

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 0' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `school_info` where (`school_name` LIKE %ok% or `address_1` LIKE %ok% or `address_2` LIKE %ok% or `address_3` LIKE %ok% or `address_4` LIKE %ok% or `county` LIKE %ok% or `postcode` LIKE %ok% or `head_teacher_email` LIKE %ok% or `head_teacher_first` LIKE %ok% or `head_teacher_last` LIKE %ok%) order by `school_name` asc offset 0)","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/globalrecruit\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `skip(n)`, it adds an `offset n` to the query, as you noticed. And when you do `take(n)`, it adds a limit of n to the query. The limit then overrides the offset when the actual query is constructed.

But by `take(0)`, you're saying you want zero results back. Eloquent thinks you don't want to apply a limit and so doesn't. Instead, only the offset is left, and doesn't in itself constitute a valid query.

Make sure the `take()` value is larger than zero, and you should be fine. :)

(Note: this is not completely true for unionised queries, but that's a different thing altogether.)